# How to use twitter application only credential to upload a media and then use it twitter api v2 for posting tweet

Tags: node.js, twitter-oauth, twitter-api-v2, twitter-api-v1

As of now there is not functionality to upload media using twitter v2 api, so i have to use api v1.1 for this, but due to this i have to take authenticate user two times, so how to upload media using v1.1 with application api_key, access_token etc. So i can the media_ids from this and use this in twitter v2 api when posting tweet

Comment: There's a [suggestion on X developer forum](https://twittercommunity.com/t/how-can-i-upload-media-using-api-v2/177887/9) to use OAuth1.0a for everything as the V2 APIs also support it. So, the users only need to authenticate once.